# Pythagorean Theorem for inclusive Kullback-Leibler

Tags: information-theory, kullback-leibler, projection

Let $\mu$ be some probability measure and consider its information projection defined by $P_* = \arg\min_{P \in \mathcal{P}} KL(P || \mu)$ and $\mathcal{P}$ is some convex family of probability measure. $P_*$ satisfies the following inequality
$$
KL(P || \mu) \geq KL(P || P_*) + KL(P_* || \mu), \quad \forall P \in \mathcal{P}
$$
which can be interpreted as some sort of Pythagora theorem.

I'm wondering if any analogous result is valid for the inclusive KL projection, i.e. if we let $P_* = \arg\min_{P \in \mathcal{P}} KL(\mu || P)$.